# git diff file outside work tree with some commit

Tags: git

Imagine a directory setup that looks something like this:

- my-git-project

  - `.git` and stuff
  - some-file.txt
- some-directory-that-is-not-version-controlled

  - some-file.txt

My goal, is to compare the version of some-file.txt that is outside the git directory, with the version that is on some OTHER branch inside the git repo.  That is, I do NOT want to compare against HEAD.

Here are some constraints I'm working under:

- Hard constraint: can't modify any files outside the git directory
- Firm (but not hard) constraint: I don't want to switch branches
- Soft constraint: I prefer not modify any files in the git directory, but I suspect there's no way to avoid that.

What's the easiest way to proceed here?  None of the incantations mentioned here seem to apply:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: I'd consider using an external diff program, not the git one.

Comment: You mean something like `git show-me some-file.txt my-branch | diff ../some-dir/some-file.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You could write the file from the other branch to disk *inside* your working directory, then run diff against it:

```
git show your-branch:path/to/file > myfile
git diff --no-index myfile /path/to/outside/myfile
```

Comment: hmm... would this work? `git show your-branch:path/to/file | git diff /dev/stdin  /path/to/outside/myfile`

Comment: Bash process substitution: `git diff <(git show your-branch:path/to/file) /path/to/outside/myfile`

Comment: @MarkVY no, because `git diff` does not read from stdin. If you are using Bash, you could try process substitution as suggested by user phd, but I think this didn't work in the past (perhaps it does now)

Comment: @knittl "*…didn't work in the past…*" In git-bash? I never was a Windows user so I really don't know git-bash limitations.

Comment: @phd no, with regular GNU Bash on GNU+Linux systems. The output would only contain `+/-pipe:[123456789]` when using process substitution and not the diff of the actual contents. <s>Perhaps it has since been fixed</s> Just tested, still happens with Git 2.39

Comment: did not realize git diff doesn't like stdin; I'll try GNU diff instead then; I know that one is okay with stdin for sure